# Sum based on two factors

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, grouping

I have a dataset where I have the variables: year, rcode(recipient code), promised aid, provided aid. 
What I want to find is the sum for the aid variables for each country (there are 194) for each year (2002-2012). There are multiple promises and payments each year, but I want the total. So basically, 2002, Afghanistan, $20 million promised, 18$ million provided, and so on.
How do I calculate all of these sums?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [how and what to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions, and then provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), including sample data.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(year, rcode) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you provide no data, this is untested, but I believe that what you want is:

```
with(MyData, aggregate(promised_aid, by=list(year, rcode), FUN=sum))
with(MyData, aggregate(provided_aid, by=list(year, rcode), FUN=sum))
```